# creating this specific cell array in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array, erase

I want to create this particular cell array. I don't want to do it manually,

`a = {'1. ','2. ','3. ','4. ', ........upto length(txt)}`

I thought of create initially numbers with `1:length(txt)` and append it to `'.'` to create cell array `a`, But  I am facing many errors there.

So that I can use erase function with argument as `a`

`erase(txt,a)`, where `txt` contains these numbers at the starting as an example it goes as

`1. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

`2. yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy`

`3. zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz`

So on......

So the output when I run `erase` will be like

`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

`yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy`

`zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use strings.

```
match = (1:length(txt)) + ". ";
```

Now you can use `erase` just like before.

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
dotspace = '. '
for k = 1:length(txt)
    match{k} = [num2str(k,'%d') dotspace];
end
```